# Hosted Application is just accessiable on the server

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-6, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have two projects,one of the is `ASP.NET core API` and another one is `Angular`.I hosted both of them on the same server.
`API` is hosted like `myip:2020` and angular app hosted like `mydomain.com` `(default port)` .

when I run these two websites they are working  fine on the server but when I enter `mydomain.com` from my local computer it return `timeout gateway`.

In console it says that `make sure myip:2020 is accessible`.

Comment: Could please tell me how you bind the mydomain.com with the server's IP? Do you buy the domain and add its DNS record?

Comment: I added new forwarded zone in dns according to some tutorials.its w